# Get a list of users along with there group membership?

Tags: python, django

I want to get a queryset along with their group membership to avoid expensive additional database hits and to make managing stuff in the template much easier.

Initially I tried to prefetch the groups a user belongs to:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    User.objects.filter(is_active=True).prefetch_related('groups')
```

But then it makes it difficult to show and hide things in the template based on the groups:

```
{{ user.groups.all }}
```

gives

```
<QuerySet [<Group: Managers>]>
```

Then I though perhaps an annotation may be better with a `is_manager` and `is_head` eg:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, Case, Value, When

def get_queryset(self):
    '''Return both active and inactive users for managers
    Annotate with is_manager = True/False
    '''
    query = When(groups__name__in=[MANAGER_GROUP_NAME, ], then=Value(1))
    return self.model.objects.all().annotate(
            is_manager=Case(
                query,
                default=Value(0),
                output_field=BooleanField()
            )
        )
```

Which worked okay but gave me an error:

```
Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'my_site.auth_group.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

But would be easy to use in the template with:

```
{% if user.is_manager %} Manager {% else %} Normal user {% endif %}
```

Is there an easier way to do it?

**Edit:**

The final query:

```
self.model.objects.prefetch_related('groups').all().annotate(
            is_manager=Case(
                When(
                    groups__id__exact=1, then=True
                ), default=False, output_field=BooleanField()
            )
        ).values("pk", "id", "email", "is_manager")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice attempt with your approach.

Firstly, if possible consider using group ids instead of group names to identify `managers`. Will dramatically improve query performance and spelling related bugs.

Following is a quick snippet that I tried and is working for me. (on postgres).

```
User.objects.prefetch_related("groups").annotate(
    is_super=Case(
        When(
            groups__id__in=[1, 2,3 ], then=1
        ), default=0, output_field=IntegerField()
    )
).order_by("id").values_list("id", "username", "is_super")
```

Comment: Ah, I am getting amysql related error: `Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'example_db.users_user_groups.group_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: Interesting, @surfer190 can you try adding the group_by group_id in the query? Can be done by adding `.values()`

Comment: Ah Perfect. I was getting an error where the `pk` was needed by the outputting table so just added it to the values: `.values("pk", "id", "email", "is_manager")`. I'll accept your answer and edit the question with my exact query.

Comment: Is there no way to return a queryset instead?

Comment: @surfer190 Yep. You can just remove .values() from the end. You'll get a normal queryset. You should be able to access the annotated column like `user.is_manager`

Comment: When I do that I get that `full_group_by` issue

Comment: @surfer190 My bad, remove the `values_list` from the end.